# How's TD Waterhouse compared to other E-brokerage services available in Canada?

Tags: canada, online-brokerage

How's TD Waterhouse compared to other E-brokerage services available in Canada? I'm a novice investor, so probably at this point only the fees and diversity of available commodities are a requirement.

Comment: What does "diversity of available commodities" mean?

Answer (score 1):

I use TD Waterhouse for my passive invest-and-hold strategy. It works very well for that. The web interface means I don't need to interact with a person, and the MER is comparatively low. TD Waterhouse offers a sufficient range of indexed mutual funds for my needs, but my needs are very simple.

[Canadian Couch Potato](http://canadiancouchpotato.com/) (a blog which advocates a passive, index-based investment approach) compares rates and offerings for [Canadian Index Funds](http://canadiancouchpotato.com/canadian-index-funds/) and [Canadian ETFs](http://canadiancouchpotato.com/canadian-etfs/).

Hopefully someone else can fill you in with how the various E-brokerage services compare for more active investors.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used TD Waterhouse.  When I chose a brokerage, my dad recommended [the Globe and Mail's annual brokerage rankings](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/globe-investor/2011-online-broker-rankings/qtrade-keeps-its-lock-on-no-1-in-globes-annual-survey/article2233815/).  The rankings still seem like a good resource, even nowadays.

(By the way, the link I provided is to the main rankings article—the most useful part—of the 2011 rankings.  Click "Detailed rankings table" at the top to see each brokerage's numerical scores in each category.)